# How to add data from db into textbox PowerBI

Tags: odbc, powerbi

I have a db table some text is present in tables. I was hoping that in someway I could fetch the data from there in powerBI using DAX or M into the textbox. please suggest something

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Text boxes are just for static text.
Try writing a Measure in DAX and displaying the result in a Card.

Comment: As such it was my second option, but I was hoping more of a long text data rather than a card.. Also is there any way to d olive commenting